# save a Dataframe in pyspark streaming

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm looking to store a PySpark DataFrame in streaming, make changes to it for each batch, and then save the updated DataFrame again using foreachBatch. What's the simplest way to accomplish this.

i am using checkpoint for the stream.

**My Code Structure:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.streaming import StreamingQuery

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

checkpoint_dir = "/path/to/checkpoint"

input_df = spark.readStream.format("your_input_source").load()

def process_batch(df, batch_id):
   pass


query = (
    input_df.writeStream
    .foreachBatch(process_batch)
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir)
    .start()
)

query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreachBatch` operator is really a type of sink that allows you to write the resulting DataFrame at the end of each micro-batch to a place of your choosing (that isn't natively supported with any built-in connectors). For example, this could be an OLTP database that doesn't have a Spark connector yet, or you might need to write to multiple sinks. Those should really be the only reasons to use `foreachBatch`.

You should not try to do data processing in `foreachBatch` if you can use streaming operators instead, such as select/filter, deduplication, windowed aggregation, or [arbitrary stateful operations in Python](https://www.databricks.com/blog/python-arbitrary-stateful-processing-structured-streaming). (Disclaimer: that blog is from Databricks, where I work, but it doesn't have any Databricks-specific stuff.)

If you are absolutely sure none of those solutions work for you, you can transform your DataFrame in `process_batch` and write it somewhere.

So, your code should end up looking something like:

```py
query = (
    input_df
    # Apply built-in operators, such as a filter or deduplication
    .filter("foo > 10")
    # Fill out the parameters if you're deduplicating
    .dropDuplicatesWithinWatermark(...)
    .writeStream
    # process_batch should write to a non-built-in sink
    # If the sink is built-in, use .format to specify it
    .foreachBatch(process_batch)
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir)
    .start()
)
```